# Command to insert a string between each character in another string

Tags: strings

I would like a command `\initials` that takes a string and inserts another string (e.g., `~`) between each character. So `\initials{GRRM}` would be typeset as `G~R~R~M`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An expandable solution that works correctly for umlauts and other non-ASCII characters in 8bit engines:

```
\documentclass{article}

% unexpanded will tokenize the `~` before \ExplSyntaxOn, making it the active
% tilde
\unexpanded{\ExplSyntaxOn\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\initials{O{~}m}}
  { \fredrik_initials:nn {#1} {#2} }
\cs_new:Npn \fredrik_initials:nn #1#2
  {
    \exp_not:e
      {
        \use:e
          {
            \exp_not:N \use_none:nn
            \text_map_function:nN {#2} \__fredrik_initials:nw
            \use_none:nnn \q_stop \use_none:n {#1}
          }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__fredrik_initials:nw #1 #2 \q_stop \use_none:n #3
  {
    \exp_not:n { \exp_not:n {#3} } \exp_not:n { \exp_not:n {#1} }
    #2 \q_stop \use_none:n {#3}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\initials{FOOBÄR}

\initials[*]{FOOBÄR}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using `*` rather than `~` so it is visible for debugging.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\initials#1{\xinitials#1\relax}
\def\xinitials#1#2{#1\ifx\relax#2\else*\expandafter\xinitials\expandafter#2\fi}


\begin{document}

\initials{GRRM}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe your initials aren't just ASCII characters. In this case you need something deeper than just processing byte by byte: the text is split grapheme by grapheme into a sequence which is “used” adding the desired tokens in between each item.

Since `~` cannot easily be used in the `expl3` programming environment, I take an indirect approach, defining a generic command and specializing it for inserting `~` when it has the usual meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\insertbetween}{mm}
 {% #1 = text, #2 = what to insert
  \fredrik_initials:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__fredrik_initials_in_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fredrik_initials:nn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__fredrik_initials_in_seq
  \text_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__fredrik_initials_in_seq { ##1 }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__fredrik_initials_in_seq { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\initials}{m}{\insertbetween{#1}{~}}

\begin{document}

\initials{ČÉABÔ}

\insertbetween{ČÉABÔ}{*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here, I use a token cycle to accomplish the task.  After each "character" that is read from the input stream, a check is performed to see if it is the last token in the stream (when the next 'peeked' token is `\empty` while the group depth `\tcdepth` is 0).

If it is not the end of the stream, the tokens that comprise the user-defined `\myfill` are added after the echoed token itself.

This approach has the added advantage that non-characters (groups, macros, and spaces) are echoed to the output stream, without the addition of `\myfill`.  Therefore, as in the 3rd example, internal italics can be preserved over part of the input stream.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\initials[1]{\tokencycle
  {\addcytoks{##1}\tcpeek{\z}%
   \ifx\empty\z
     \ifnum\tcdepth=0 \else\addcytoks[1]{\myfill}\fi
   \else\addcytoks[1]{\myfill}\fi}% CHARACTERS
  {\processtoks{##1}}% GROUPS
  {\addcytoks{##1}}%MACROS
  {\addcytoks{##1}}%SPACES
  #1\endtokencycle}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\myfill{~}
\initials{GRRM}

\renewcommand\myfill{*}
\initials{GRRM}

\initials{G\textit{RR}M}

Detokenized: ``\detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}''
\end{document}
```

[image]